# Was this person an owner of the Darksaber?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels, darksaber

**Spoilers for *The Clone Wars*, *Rebels*, and season 2 of *The Mandalorian***

---

The history of the Darksaber is that it was passed down through Clan Vizsla for years until Maul won it from Pre Vizsla in a duel.  This made him the rightful heir, and it granted him the loyalty of the Mandalorians for a time.  However, Maul eventually drifted away from ruling Mandalore, but kept the Darksaber.

No one ever won the Darksaber from Maul.  Sabine found it in his cave on Dathomir and took it, training with it.  Ursa told her that it didn't count as Sabine's unless she won it in combat from Maul.  However, in this episode, Gar Saxon steals the Darksaber from Sabine and fights her using it.  Sabine defeats him, but it is unclear if this means that she is now the rightful heir of the weapon.  The [Wookieepedia article on the Darksaber](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Darksaber) says "Sabine became the rightful wielder of the Darksaber after defeating Imperial Viceroy Gar Saxon in a duel."  I don't want to quote the Wookieepedia article as fact, but it does make one wonder.  Technically, the Darksaber was never Sabine's or Gar Saxon's - both of them just sort of stole it and then fought using it, but neither won it from Maul, who rightfully did so, by Mandalorian law.  And the issue is about winning the Darksaber in battle, not simply defeating the wielder, or that would technically make Obi-Wan the heir, since he killed Maul.

In season 4 of *Rebels*, Sabine passes the Darksaber to Bo-Katan, saying that Bo-Katan should be the ruler of Mandalore.  She accepts this and, at a later date, ends up losing the Darksaber to Moff Gideon.  Din then wins it from Moff Gideon, technically making Din the heir.  Bo-Katan refuses to take the Darksaber, saying that, in Mandalorian custom, it must be fought for.

This seems to go directly against her accepting it from Sabine in *Rebels* - in that instance, she peacefully took it to lead Mandalore.  She refuses it from Din because he won it in combat, which seems to cement him as Mandalore's leader.  Was this not the case with Sabine - was the Darksaber ever hers?

After Maul, it would seem to be that Sabine is the wielder of the weapon.  She is drawn to it, she trains with it, and she leads Mandalorians with it.  When Ursa tells her that she must win it in combat, Sabine technically "wins" it from Gar Saxon, but it was definitely never his weapon, so would that count?

If the Darksaber doesn't belong to Sabine, that leaves more questions, as this shouldn't technically mean that she can just pass it to Bo-Katan, does it?  That would still go against custom, as no one won it.

So - was the Darksaber rightfully won by Sabine when she fought Gar Saxon?  Or does that not count, as Gar Saxon was not its wielder before her?

Comment: Do we know the circumstances of  Moff Gideon's acquisition of the Darksaber?

Comment: @WiggotheWookie I don't think we do at this point, only that he fairly won it from Bo-Katan.  She did say outright that he took it from her, so I assume it takes place in between Rebels and The Mandalorian, because Bo-Katan is given the Darksaber by Sabine in Rebels and then has lost it in The Mandalorian.

Comment: This question is already answered here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244016/why-did-this-character-accept-the-darksaber/

Comment: @PeterNielsen  That's also my question, but it's about a different aspect of the Darksaber.  And it didn't get answered there, and I haven't accepted the answer - it doesn't acknowledge Sabine's ownership of the Darksaber.